# How to delete all keys in Redis except ones which start with a prefix in Laravel

Tags: laravel, caching, redis

I want to delete all the keys in redis except ones that start with:

`cars-`

I am able to clear all keys or specific keys starting with a prefix.

Can anyone advise how I could do this in Laravel?

Comment: how many keys do you have ? any ttl on any of that ?

Comment: Sorry couldn't tell exact number but we store a lot. We cache responses back from API. Recently I have added a prefix to some keys we want to keep "cars-" and we want to clear all other keys (in emergency situations). Any advise how we can clear all keys except with the prefix (in php / laravel) would be appreciated.

Comment: what i would do is; move all the keys (starts with car) to another redis database no 1(by default it is stored in 0) - and then flushdb on database 0 - and the move your keys from database no 1 to database no 0. it will be not a flawless process but it works. please check https://redis.io/commands/move command for it.